# Google Chrome Storage Saving

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

So I've created an options page and I'm trying to save the values of a form to storage, but I keep getting the console error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sync' of undefined".

HTML Form:

```
    <h3 class="option">When Search Tab is opened the Search Panel should be:</h3>
    <select id="searchPanel" class="selectOption">
        <option value="open">Open</option>
        <option value="closed">Closed</option>
    </select>

    <h3 class="option">The Search Bar Background Color Should Be:</h3>
    <select id="barBackground" class="selectOption">
        <option value="#000000">Black</option>
        <option value="#ffffff">White</option>
        <option value="#333333">Grey</option>
        <option value="#006633">Green</option>
        <option value="#336699">Blue</option>
        <option value="#990000">Red</option>
        <option value="#CC6600">Orange</option>
    </select>

    <h3 class="option">The Search Bar Text Color Should Be:</h3>
    <select id="barColor" class="selectOption">
        <option value="#000000">Black</option>
        <option value="#ffffff">White</option>
        <option value="#333333">Grey</option>
        <option value="#006633">Green</option>
        <option value="#336699">Blue</option>
        <option value="#990000">Red</option>
        <option value="#CC6600">Orange</option>
    </select>
```

Javascript:

```
function loadOptions() {

    var searchPanelDefault = 'open';
    var barBackgroundDefault= '#000000';
    var barColorDefault = '#ffffff';

    chrome.storage.local.get('searchPanelOption', function (x) {
        if(!x.searchPanel) {
            searchPanel.value = 'open';
        } else {
            searchPanel.value = (x.SearchPanel);
        }
   });
   chrome.storage.local.get('barBackgroundOption', function (x) {
        if(!x.searchPanel) {
            searchPanel.value = '#000000';
        } else {
            searchPanel.value = (x.SearchPanel);
        }
   });
   chrome.storage.local.get('barColorOption', function (x) {
        if(!x.searchPanel) {
            SearchPanel.value = '#ffffff';
        } else {
            SearchPanel.value = (x.SearchPanel);
        }
   });
}

function saveOptions() {
    var searchPanelDisplay = searchPanel.value;
    var barBackgroundDisplay = barBackground.value;
    var barColorDisplay = barColor.value;

    if (!searchPanelDisplay) {
        console.log('Error: No SearchPanel Value');
        searchPanelDisplay = 'open';
    } else if(!barBackgroundDisplay) {
        console.log('Error: No barBackground Value');
        barBackgroundDisplay = '#000000';
    } else if(!barColorDisplay) {
        console.log('Error: No barColor Value');
        barColorDisplay = '#ffffff';
    }

    chrome.storage.sync.set({'searchPanelOption': SearchPanelDisplay}, function() {
        console.log('SearchPanel saved');
    });
    chrome.storage.sync.set({'barBackgroundOption': barBackgroundDisplay}, function() {
        console.log('SearchPanel saved');
    });
    chrome.storage.sync.set({'barColorOption': barColorDisplay}, function() {
        console.log('SearchPanel saved');
    });
}

function eraseOptions() {
    location.reload();
}
```

Manifest:

```
{
    "background": {
       "persistent": false,
       "scripts": [ "script/background.js" ]
    },
    "chrome_url_overrides": {
       "newtab": "dashboard.html"
    },
    "description": "Upgrade Your New Tab to SearchTab",
    "icons": {
    "16": "images/icons/icon16.jpg",
    "48": "images/icons/icon48.jpg",
    "128": "images/icons/icon128.jpg"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "SearchTab",
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "offline_enabled": true,
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'",
    "permissions": ["storage", "unlimitedStorage", "tabs"],
    "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

EDIT:
New Error Message:

Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Comment: Did you declare `"storage"` permission?

Comment: Yes, I just added my manifest

Comment: How are you testing it?

Comment: It loads and then I change the values of the three form buttons, then when I click save (which triggers saveOptions() ) it gives me an error in the console.

Comment: I mean, have you properly reloaded the extension, and then opened the page via options link? I know it's stupid, but I'm trying to eliminate the "I opened the html file directly" scenario. Put another way, what is the full URL displayed when you open the page?

Comment: Yes I've opened the settings from my new tab page and I've gotten the same results

Comment: Also, for whatever reason your code _loads_ from `local` but _saves_ to `sync`.

Comment: Oh, its because I've tried both local and sync and gotten the same error, I forgot to change the load back to sync, I'll fix that.

Comment: Please double-check that 1) you reloaded the extension in the `chrome://extensions/` list, 2) the option page loads with URL `chrome-extension://...`

Comment: As said by Xan, the only thing that may be causing that error is that you haven't reloaded your extension correctly. Go to `chrome://extensions/`, enable developer mode and hit CTRL+R, or click on "reload" beside your extension. If this doesn't work try removing and reinstalling it.

Comment: @Xan I have done this three times, it isn't working. Trust me I've reloaded it and I've updated the manifest version and everything. It has to be some other problem. I just can't find it : /

Comment: Now I'm getting a new error message when I click the save button: Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Comment: @Nesiehr That 100% indicates that you were not loading the page as an extension page before, but just by opening the html file. Now the answer to your problem lies here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution

Comment: @Xan thank you, but now that I'm not getting any errors it is also not outputting the console.log, so I'm not sure if the function actually works.